# String Manipulation Using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following scenario, I am wondering if a better solution could be written with Regular Expressions for which I am not very familiar with yet.  I am seeing holes in my basic c# string manipulation even though it somewhat works.  Your thoughts and ideas are most appreciated.

Thanks much,

Craig

Given the string "story" below, write a script to do the following:

1. Variable text is enclosed by `{ }`.
2. If the variable text is blank, remove any other text enclosed in `[ ]`.
3. Text to be removed can be nested deep with `[ ]`.

Format:

```
    XYZ Company [- Phone: [({404}) ]{321-4321} [Ext: {6789}]]
```

Examples:

1. All variable text filled in.

   ```
   XYZ Company - Phone: (404) 321-4321 Ext: 6789
   ```
2. No Extension entered, remove "Ext:".

   ```
   XYZ Company - Phone: (404) 321-4321
   ```
3. No Extension and no area code entered, remove "Ext:" and "( ) ".

   ```
   XYZ Company - Phone: 321-4321
   ```
4. No extension, no phone number, and no area code, remove "Ext:" and "( ) " and "- Phone: ".

   ```
   XYZ Company
   ```

Here is my solution with plain string manipulation.

```
private string StoryManipulation(string theStory)
    {
        // Loop through story while there are still curly brackets
        while (theStory.IndexOf("{") > 0)
        {
            // Extract the first curly text area
            string lcCurlyText = StringUtils.ExtractString(theStory, "{", "}");                

            // Look for surrounding brackets and blank all text between
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lcCurlyText))
            {
                for (int lnCounter = theStory.IndexOf("{"); lnCounter >= 0; lnCounter--)
                {
                    if (theStory.Substring(lnCounter - 1, 1) == "[")
                    {
                        string lcSquareText = StringUtils.ExtractString(theStory.Substring(lnCounter - 1), "[", "]");
                        theStory = StringUtils.ReplaceString(theStory, ("[" + lcSquareText + "]"), "", false);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Replace current curly brackets surrounding the text
                theStory = StringUtils.ReplaceString(theStory, ("{" + lcCurlyText + "}"), lcCurlyText, false);
            }
        }
        // Replace all brackets with blank (-1 all instances)
        theStory = StringUtils.ReplaceStringInstance(theStory, "[", "", -1, false);
        theStory = StringUtils.ReplaceStringInstance(theStory, "]", "", -1, false);
        return theStory.Trim();
    }
```

Comment: Do I get that right... you search for `{...}` if it's empty or contains only whitespace, you want to remove the "parent-level" `[...]` enclosing the matched `{...}`? Also, if area code and extension are entered, but the main phone number is omitted, you still want to remove everything, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Any text is outside of [...] it is left alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with nested structures is generally beyond the scope of regular expressions. But I think there is a solution, if you run the regex replacement in a loop, starting from the inside out. You will need a callback-function though (a `MatchEvaluator`):

```
string ReplaceCallback(Match match)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(match.Groups[2])
        return "";
    else
        return match.Groups[1]+match.Groups[2]+match.Groups[3];
}
```

Then you can create the evaluator:

```
MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceCallback);
```

And then you can call this in a loop until the replacement does not change anything any more:

```
newString = Regex.Replace(
    oldString,
    @"
    \[    # a literal [
    (     # start a capturing group. this is what we access with "match.Groups[1]"
        [^{}[\]]
          # a negated character class, that matches anything except {, }, [ and ]
        * # arbitrarily many of those
    )     # end of the capturing group
    \{    # a literal {
    ([^{}[\]]*)
          # the same thing as before, we will access this with "match.Groups[2]"
    }     # a literal }
    ([^{}[\]]*)
          # "match.Groups[3]"
    ]     # a literal ]
    ",
    evaluator,
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
);
```

Here is the whitespace-free version of the regex:

```
\[([^{}[\]]*)\{([^{}[\]]*)}([^{}[\]]*)]
```

Comment: Wow that was fast and I think is what I was looking for!

Comment: Although the closing literal brackets/braces don't _need_ to be escaped (and you haven't), for clarity it is best practice to go ahead and escape them anyway (IMHO). Text is cheap and readability should always be a top priority. Also, why not just write the regex out once in free-spacing mode with comments built-in to start off with and be done with it-> _self-documentation!_. Once again, nice explanation. +1

Comment: @ridgerunner see, I leave the escaping out where possible exactly for the reason of readability :D. I guess it's a matter of taste then. the freespacing thing... yup, that is something I need to get used to for these answers (when using or writing regexes for myself, I prefer them to be oneliners, because I can usually grasp their meaning faster than by reading long explanations)

Comment: Yeah - no need to comment the short ones. But for anything non-trivial, commenting is essential. After many years writing assembly language I developed the habit of commenting _every instruction_ (regex is low level too). But there is also an art to commenting - no need to state the obvious and one must keep things concise. [This page](http://jmrware.com/articles/2011/fluxbb_jmr_dev/viewtopic.php?id=3) shows the commenting style I've developed for complex regexes. Indentation allows visually seeing bracket matching and alternatives for deeply nested structures (YMMV). Cheers.